# What's the Vandermonde matrix of 4 points?

Tags: interpolation

I'm learning about Vandermonde matrix to get monomial basis.

Suppose I have 4 points $(-1, 2),~ (0,7),~ (1,22) $ and $ (2,71)$

I was taught how to create the Vandermonde matrix using arbitrary numbers:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 &&x^1&& x^2 &&x^3&&\dots&& x^n\\
1 &&y^1&& y^2 &&y^3 &&\dots&&y^n\\
1&& z^1&& z^2&& z^3 &&\dots&&z^n\\
1&& r^1&& r^2&& r^3&&\dots&& r^n\end{bmatrix}$$

where `n = number of points - 1`. I'm not sure if I was taught this correctly.

Is this the Vandermonde matrix, given the points:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&& 1&& -1&& 1\\
1 &&0  &&0 &&0\\
1 &&1 && 1 &&1\\
1&& 2&&  4 &&8\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Well I guess you may not have been taught this particular properly if you were just given a vague definition and hurried along

Comment: @Certainlynotadog I really don't think I was, my teacher tends to teach vaguely and self-learn to an extent.Is this vandermonde matrix correct for 4 points? I know how to do it with 3.

Comment: Actually it’s not exactly correct. For $x$ coordinates we have $$\begin{bmatrix}1&&-1&&1&&-1\\1&&0&&0&&0\\1&&1&&1&&1\\1&&2&&4&&8\end{bmatrix}$$. And, I’m not sure if the third row is correct. It’s possible it’s undefined since the first element could be $0^0$.